# How can I change the default message of invalid credentials on OAuthServerException in Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am developing an API using Laravel Passport for authentication and my problem is that I cannot change the default message when the login fail due to invalid credentials.

**LoginController.php**

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    return $this->issueToken($request, 'password');
}
```

**IssueTokenTrait.php**

```
public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = "") {
    $params = [
        'grant_type' => $grantType,
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
        'scope' => $scope
    ];

    if($grantType !== 'social'){
        $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;
    }

    $request->request->add($params);
    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

    return Route::dispatch($proxy);
}
```

When I put invalid credentials, it returns:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_credentials",
    "error_description": "The user credentials were incorrect.",
    "message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
}
```

I want to change this message because I want the message to depend on the language.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but i try my best to answer you.

```
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;

public function issueToken(Request $request, $grantType, $scope = "",ServerRequestInterface $service_request) {
    $params = [
        'grant_type' => $grantType,
        'client_id' => $this->client->id,
        'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
        'scope' => $scope
    ];

    if($grantType !== 'social'){
        $params['username'] = $request->username ?: $request->email;
    }

    $request->request->add($params);
    $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token', 'POST');

  throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('access_token', object_get($error, 
  'error.message'));

    return Route::dispatch($proxy);
}
```

Change `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` under:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {

    ...

    $class = get_class($exception);

    ...


        if ($class == 'League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException' ){
            return response()->json([
              'code'=>$exception->getHttpStatusCode(),
              'error'=>$exception->getMessage(),
              'error_type'=>$exception->getErrorType()
            ],
            $exception->getHttpStatusCode());
        } 

        ...

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. In this case, the `OAuthServerException` is thrown every time, and not when the credentials are invalid, also when I call to the `issueToken` function, what would I pass in `service_request` parameter?